# How to pass form field values to a service method in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm learning Grails and I'm having a problem. I implemented scaffolding to give me the basic web forms I want and I auto-generated the controller. In the controller the create code will accept the input of a URL from a field on the form and then call a service method, let's call it executeUrl() which uses that url in some logic, which is already done.

So I have a class called myUrl that has a property urlName.

```
 myUrl aUrl = new Url(params)
 UrlService.executeUrl(aUrl)
```

The issue is I need to fill aUrl.urlName with something since I'm passing null above. When the user enters a url in the create form how do I grab that value and pass it to executeUrl()? Hopefully this makes sense, the tutorials have helped up to this point but I'm stuck. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So starting with your form field, assume you have something like:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
```

In your controller you can grab the url from params like

```
def url = params.url
```

If you have a field named url in your MyUrl class you can just pass params to the constructor and groovy will bind the value for you, naming is key here

```
class MyUrl {
    String url
}

new MyUrl( params )
```

Comment: It looks like I have errors in my generated form.gsp file.   <g:message code="myurl.urlName.label" default="My Url" /> is showing an error: "Cannot resolve property key". Not sure why since this is auto generated. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's just a warning, you need to have a corresponding entry in messages.properties e.g. `myurl.urlName.label=URL`